# mysqli array fetching is not getting data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to fetch result in single row but I can't run multiple rows. How can I fix this?

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from user where id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
if($stmt->execute()){
 $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $stmt->close();
 return $result;
 }
```

I Got Result Like Wise This

```
{"ID":2,"Name":"Anju"}
```

But i need to get all user result .my code is here

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from user where id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
if($stmt->execute()){
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$result[] = $row;
}
 $stmt->close();
 return $result;
}
```

I got the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in line  5

The line is:

```
while ($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

my expecting result is

```
 {"ID":1,"Name":"Obi"}, {"ID":3,"Name":"Oman"}, {"ID":4,"Name":"Anju"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from user where id=?");`
`$stmt->bindValue(1, $id);`

Try that way

And try to fetchAll instead of fetch_array

Comment: am try that i got error like `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Undefined fieldtype 1 (parameter 2) `.

Comment: did you try bindValue? from your error i see you still using bind_param()

Answer (score 0):

You could make following correction.

Change

```
$rows->fetch_assoc(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

to

```
$rows->fetch_assoc()
```

It should look like

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $rows = $stmt->get_result();
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()){
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

Suggestion : *Always specify the list of columns in your `SELECT`, which makes query execution faster.*

Please read **[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**